# What exactly does `eli5.show_weights` display for a classification model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, eli5

I used `eli5` to apply the permutation procedure for feature importance. In the [documentation](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blackbox/permutation_importance.html), there is some explanation and a small example but it is not clear.

I am using a `sklearn SVC` model for a classification problem.

**My question is:** Are these weights the change (decrease/increase) of the accuracy when the specific feature is shuffled OR is it the SVC weights of these features?

In [this medium article](https://medium.com/towards-artificial-intelligence/how-to-use-scikit-learn-eli5-library-to-compute-permutation-importance-9af131ece387), the author states that these values show the *reduction in model performance by the reshuffle of that feature.* But not sure if that's indeed the case.

Small example:

```py
from sklearn import datasets
import eli5
from eli5.sklearn import PermutationImportance
from sklearn.svm import SVC, SVR

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]
y = iris.target

clf = SVC(kernel='linear')
perms = PermutationImportance(clf, n_iter=1000, cv=10, scoring='accuracy').fit(X, y)

print(perms.feature_importances_)
print(perms.feature_importances_std_)

[0.38117333 0.16214   ]
[0.1349115  0.11182505]

eli5.show_weights(perms)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some deep research. 
After going through the source code here is what I believe for the case where `cv` is used and is not `prefit` or `None`. I use a K-Folds scheme for my application. I also use a SVC model thus, `score` is the accuracy in this case.

By looking at the `fit` method of the`PermutationImportance` object, the `_cv_scores_importances` are computed (https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5/blob/master/eli5/sklearn/permutation_importance.py#L202). The specified cross-validation scheme is used and the `base_scores, feature_importances` are returned using the test data (function: `_get_score_importances` inside `_cv_scores_importances`).

By looking at `get_score_importances` function (https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5/blob/master/eli5/permutation_importance.py#L55), we can see that `base_score` is the score on the non shuffled data and `feature_importances` (called differently there as: `scores_decreases`) are defined as  non shuffled score - shuffled score (see https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5/blob/master/eli5/permutation_importance.py#L93)

Finally, the errors (`feature_importances_std_`) are the SD of the above `feature_importances` (https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5/blob/master/eli5/sklearn/permutation_importance.py#L209) and the `feature_importances_` is the mean of the above `feature_importances` (non-shuffled score minus (-) shuffled score).

Answer (score -1):

A fair bit shorter answer to your original question, regardless of the setting for the `cv` parameter, eli5 will calculate the average decrease in the scorer you provide. Because you're using the sklearn wrapper, the scorer will come from scikit-learn: in your case [accuracy](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html).  Overall as a word on the package, some of these details are particularly difficult to figure out without going into the deeper into the source code, might be worth trying to submit a pull request to make the documentation more detailed where possible.